# Magento cache is reusing bugy code resulting in site death with "Too many connections"

Tags: mysql, magento

In my Magento store there is a piece of code that is not closing the DB connection (it seems). Normally I don't see any problems. However the problem arises when I enable caching. After a few hours, the site grounds to a halt and eventually it dies with the MySQL error "Too many connections".
It seems that the "bad" piece of code is cached and reused and therefore gets worse and worse until...death.

I'm scratching my head to find out where this rogue piece of code is being called from(of course there could be more than 1 problem).
I doubt it's a core problem otherwise I probably would have heard of it whilst Googling the issue. So that just leaves 3rd part modules and code I have written.

One option would be to disable all modules and re-enable each one until the problem occurs. But of course it might not happen for several hours (and when it did you just know it would be in the middle of the night ;)). Then of course it might not a 3rd party issue but something I have done. And also I need certain modules in my store for it to function properly (payment gateways etc).

So I'm after suggestions on how to track this down...

I've enabled MySQL logging but it doesn't really tell me all that much.

Any ideas?

Magento 1.7.0.2 and APC with Apache 2

Comment: Painful as it is you need to disable the modules one by one to find out whats causing the error

Comment: Did you analyse the mysql slow queries ?

Comment: I haven't reviewed them yet but it is a good idea. Will post back with findings

Comment: Ok so there is nothing coming up in the slow MySQL log. This is a head scratcher!